# Suggestions for how to write a service in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, web-services, architecture

I am building an application which will send status requests to users (via email & sms) on a regular basis. I want to execute the service each hour which will:

- Query the database for all requests that need to be sent (based on some logic)
- Send the requests through Amazon's Simple Email Service (this is already working)
- Write a record of the status request notification back to the data store

I am considering wrapping up this series of operations into a single controller with an end point that can be called remotely to kick off the process within the rails app.

Longer term, I will break this process out into an app that can be run independently of my rails app, but for now I'm just trying to keep it simple.

My first inclination is to build the following:

- Controller with the following elements:

  - A method which will orchestrate the steps outlined above (and can be called externally)
  - A call to the `status_request` model which will bring back a collection of request needing to be sent
  - A loop to iterate through the pending requests, which will:
  - Make a call to my AWS Simple Email Service module to actually send the email, and
  - Make a call to the `status_request` model to log the request back to the database
- Model:

  - A method on my `status_request` model which will bring back a collection of requests that need to be sent
  - A method in my `status_request` model which will log that a notification was sent

Since this will behave as a service that gets called periodically from an outside scheduler I don't think I'll need a view for this operation. (Will, of course, need views to show users and admins what requests have been sent, but that's later...).

As someone new to Rails, I'm asking for review of this approach and any suggestions you may have.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of a controller which Jeff pointed out exposes a security risk, you may just want to expose a rake task and use cron to invoke it on an hourly basis.

If you are still interested in building a controller, look at devise gem and its single access token, token_authenticatable, for securing the methods you are exposing.

You may also want to look at delayed_job or resque to offload the call to status_request and the loop to AWS simple service to a background worker process.

You may want a seperate controller and view for the log file so you can review progress on demand.

And if you want to get real fancy use Amazon SNS to send you alerts when the service reaches some unacceptable level of failures, backlog, etc.

Comment: did some reading about delayed_job here: https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job. Great Gem!

Answer (score 1):

Since you are trying to invoke this from an outside process, your approach should work.  You could also have a worker process that processes task when they are there.

You will need routes to expose your service, and you may want to also make security decisions.  How will the service that invokes your application authenticate so all others can't hit it at will?

Another consideration should be how many emails are you sending.  If there are enough, we may want to look into the fact that writing this sort of loop is going to be extremely top heavy; and may affect users on the current system if it's a web application.

In the end, there are many ways to do this.  I would focus on the performance/usage you expect as well as security.  There's never one perfect way to solve a problem like this, and your way should just be aware of the variables it will need to be operating within.

Comment: Thanks, Jeff. Great point about securing the end point. Ultimately this needs to be a service sitting somewhere off the web server(s). I'd like to make sure that I can factor it out later. I appreciate your answer.

Answer (score 0):

[Resque](https://github.com/defunkt/resque) and [Redis](http://redis.io/) might be helpful to you in scheduling and performing operatio n .They are simple and superfast, [here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/271-resque] is a simple tut on same.